# ag-grid angular get element ref

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to get a DOM reference on the grid element in Angular? There doesn't appear to be a straightforward way. I tried:

markup:

```
<ag-grid-angular #logGrid></ag-grid-angular>
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild('logGrid') logGrid: AgGridNg2;
```

AgGridNg2 does not have a nativeElement or ElementRef property exposed.

I also tried:

```
@ViewChild('logGrid') logGrid: ElementRef;
```

It doesn't have nativeElement property because its type is AgGridNg2 not ElementRef.

I need the DOM reference because [ag-grid doesn't expose scrollHeight](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3089) of its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a reference to the host element of the component by setting the `read` property of the [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator to `ElementRef`:

```
@ViewChild('logGrid', { read: ElementRef }) logGridElementRef: ElementRef;
```

Comment: This works a treat !   But why does Visual Studio Code continue to complain that "Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type 'AgGridAngular'"  even though (with your suggested change)  I *can* now use the nativeElement value ?